# Different electric fields

Tags: electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, potential, electromagnetic-induction

What is the difference between an $electrostatic$ and a $non-electrostatic$ electric field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electrostatic field is an electric field that is produced from a non-changing charge distribution with no current (i.e. $\mathbf J=0$ at all points in space for all time). Essentially for electrostatics we just have stationary charges and constant electric fields.

If this is not the case, then resulting electric fields are not considered to be a part of electrostatics. i.e. moving charges, EM waves, etc.

Comment: Can you also add, how that difference can affects anything else?

Comment: @GouravM What do you mean?

Comment: Like the mechanics of any particle present in there fields, etc.

Comment: @GouravM That's a pretty broad question. I don't think I can answer it unless you have a specific system in mind. And even then the comments are not a place to discuss it. If there is a system you want to learn more about, it might be good to ask a new question.